# Laravel 5 Dynamic clause WHERE from Form array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

y have this Controller with GET vars:

localhost/ordersys/public/admin/orders?provid=220001&price=500

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('Admin\OrdersController@filter'), 'role'=>'search', 'method' => 'GET')) !!} 
{!! Form::text('provid', null, array('class' => 'typeahead form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search by Provid here...')) !!}
{!! Form::text('price', null, array('class' => 'typeahead form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Price max ...')) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Search', array('class' => 'btn btn-default search-bar-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!} 

$varprovid =  Input::get('provid');
$varprice  =  Input::get('price');

   $collection = DB::table('orders')
     ->where('cod_prov', $varprovid)
     ->where('price', '<', $varprice)
     ->paginate(15);
```

This work, but how can catch the Inputs Input::get('provid'), Input::get('price') from Form and filter Collection using Where clauses dynamically. I can build array and use foreach loop? Any idea please, thanks.